# How get formulas into code

Tags: java, c++, formula

this is a general question about how to get formulas working into code. My math skills are bad and I get lost when I try to implement simple things into code.

For example how can I interpret this formula:

-What means n? or what would be y etc

```
y(n) = y (n-1) + ((x (n) - y (n-1))/slide)
```

This formula was tooken from an maxmsp object for sliding audio values 
slide~ filters an input signal logarithmically between changes in signal value. The formula is y (n) = y (n-1) + ((x (n) - y (n-1))/slide). It's particularly useful for envelope following and lowpass filtering.

Every help will be much appreciated!

Comment: presumably 'n' is the n'th sample. What is '(n)'? Shouldn't this be 'y(n)'?

Comment: Keep in mind that a mathematical formula and a program do fundamentally different things. A formula *describes* a solution, and a program *does stuff*. So you need to give the program something to do - a verb. You need to make your code *solve* the formula for example.

Comment: @Eamorr your right. it should be y(n) sorry for that. and what is x and y?

Comment: The difference is a lot smaller here than usual. This formula defines `y(n)` as a vector, with it's value derived from `x(n)`. Variable definitions and initializations convert well to formula's. Also, it's a fundamental result of computer science that programs and formula's are identical.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical use of `y(n)` corresponds to array (or `vector`) index in C++: `y[n]`.

Therefore it's straightforward:

```
std::vector<float> x = foo();
std::vector<float> y(x.size());
float slide = 10; // Random guess - you should understand x[]
y[0] = x[0]; // Start the same; there's no y[-1]
for (int n = 1; i != x.size(); ++i) {

  y[n] = y[n-1] + ((x[n] - y[n-1])/slide);

}
```

Essentially, this is the discrete equivalent of an RC filter, possibly one of the most common [Infinite Impulse Response(IIR) filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response)

Answer (score 1):

```
float y(int n, float slide)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        // TODO: figure out what to do here. i.e. what is y(0).
    }

    float nMinus1 = y(n - 1);
    return nMinus1 + (x(n) - nMinus1) / slide);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that, but I have no idea what do you mean with y(0).

Comment: That would be the value of 'y' for the first n. Since the formula uses 'Y(n - 1)' and if n was 0 then Y(0 - 1), which is Y(-1) and might not make sense.
Wherever you got that formula from *must* have a description of what each variable is and what legitimate values are.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is pretty easy.
You just need to parse the formula to make a list of tokens which will be used for creation of the syntax tree of the formula. Then you just need to evaluate the tree with the variable values you want and resolving any function entries. At the end you'll get a good math formula translator to some kind of evaluatable IR...

But talking seriously if you just need to perform some math calculation then use appropriate instruments such as MathCAD or else.
If you need to write a program which uses some formulas then implement them in code as is and use as you wish.
If you need a program which can interpret any formula.. well, read the first part of the answer :)